# Specifying a linear mixed model in lmer with replications nested within a fully crossed design

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, many-categories

I’m trying to specify a linear mixed model for a somewhat complicated, nested & crossed method comparison study with replicated measurements. The goal is to partition and compare variances. It’s more complicated than the typical introductory examples I have seen and I’m not quite sure how to do it correctly.

The data I have collected comes from a comparison of different laboratory measurement *methods* (4 levels), each evaluated for all combinations for *parameter1* (10 levels) and *parameter2* (40 levels). Measurements (repeated for each unique combination of method, parameter1 and parameter2) were done on 60 different *subjects* characterized by *sex*. Each measurement was replicated 800 times (almost 80 million rows of observation) and the difference (true value determined beforehand by a reference method - measured value) was recorded.

**Therefore: method x parameter1 x parameter2 are fully crossed (all combinations of factor levels occur once), subjects are nested within sex, and replicated measurements are nested within subject.**

Following some advice (https://mailman.ucsd.edu/pipermail/ling-r-lang-l/2011-February/000225.html, and Barr et al., 2013), I would like to initially specify a maximal random effects structure for this, i.e., to account for between-subject differences in the sensitivity to all of the conditions, and then strip down the model from there. But I’m having a really hard time wrapping my head around the formula syntax and the model logic at the same time.

I’m shooting in the dark here, but what about:

```
(1 + method*param1*param2*sex | sex/subj_id)  # which expands to
(1 + method*param1*param2*sex | sex) + (1 + method*param1*param2*sex | sex:subj_id)
```

I don’t think that’s correct, though. It seems strange to have sex on both sides of the equation.

I would be very grateful for any help.

On a related issue: I intend to regress on the difference between measured value and (known) true value: diff ~ …. Is there any reason to instead regress the known true value onto the measured value: measured ~ true + …?

Comment: In what sense do you have a measured value and a known true value? Is the response yes/no, or something like that?

Comment: Not quite. Concentrations of a protein were measured by 4 "cheap" measurement methods after its "true" concentration within each sample (subj_id) has been established by a reference method which is more precise by orders of magnitudes (and can therefore be considered, in this context, to be without measurement error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each `subj_id` is associated with one and only one value of `sex`, you need not mention `sex` in the random part of the model formula.  The model using maximal random effects would be:

`(1 + method*param1*param2 | subj_id)`

You might have some difficulty estimating the random effects for this model because of the large number of levels of your factors (which implies a very large correlation matrix).

Also, I can't think of any reason why using difference scores instead of the raw pairs of scores as your DV would cause a problem.

Comment: Wouldn't a specification including `subj_id` nested in `sex` result in different (smaller) variances for the random effects?  I.e., in a nested model, `(1+method*param1*param2|sex:subj_id)`, the variances should be smaller than in the non-nested one `(1+method*param1*param2|subj_id)`, since each value of `sex` specifies a sub-population of `subj_id`.  So, the modeler's choice in this regard (based on considerations that are currently unfathomable to me) should make a material difference to the resulting covariance parameters.  Am I right?  (I need to understand this for my current research).