# Fully nested variables: is there any valid model that includes BOTH?

Tags: mixed-model, nested-data

I am struggling to find a *valid* syntax for a (mixed?) model.

Given the following data:

```
> str(raw)
'data.frame':   69 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ sp        : Factor w/ 9 levels "sp1","sp2","sp3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ group    : Factor w/ 3 levels "group1","group2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ response: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ exp1     : num  -1.77 -1.66 -1.67 -2.03 -1.77 ...
 $ exp2     : num  -0.606 -0.486 -0.576 -0.585 -0.501 -0.497 -0.487 -0.271 -0.199 -0.2 ...
```

And the following design of factors:
(numbers are observations of each `sp` and `group` combination, they should sum up to 69, as noted above)

```
> xtabs(~ sp + group, raw, sparse=T)
    group1 group2 group3
sp1      7      .      .
sp2      5      .      .
sp3      6      .      .
sp4      .      5      .
sp5      .      9      .
sp6      .      9      .
sp7      .     10      .
sp8      .      .      9
sp9      .      .      9
```

I suspect that several syntaxes are **invalid**:
(in brackets I will specify the way to code each option in `R` for function `lme4::lmer`)
(for the sake of simplicity I only give examples of random effects with free intercept, slope not needed to discuss the issue here, right?)

1. Using `group` as a random effect `(1|group)` in a mixed model seems not to be valid because it only has 3 levels and 5-6 levels are required *to estimate an among-block variance* (Ben Bolker at his [glmm.wikidot](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) and [a document in Rpubs](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/4187))
2. Using `sp` as the random effect `(1|sp)` and leaving `group` as a fixed effect in a mixed model (`response ~ group + (1|sp)`) is not valid either, as there is no variation of `group` within each `sp`. Is this right?
   A consequence of this no-variation of `group` within each `sp` I have tested that defining the random effect as *sp nested in group* `(1|group/sp)` is *identical* to having `sp` as the only random effect `(1|sp)` ([in another CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111466/specifying-a-linear-mixed-model-in-lmer-with-replications-nested-within-a-fully)).

All of this...
...leaves me with only two **valid** models:

1. A simple linear model: `response ~ comp1 + comp2 + group`
2. A mixed model: `response ~ comp1 + comp2 + (1|sp)`

am I mistaken?
is there any valid syntax that combines `sp` and `group` in a single model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and learning, I found out that what I called "fully nested" factors is a frequent situation and there is a name for it: **Hierarchical Analysis** or **Multilevel Mixed Models**.

In this way, the random factors (`sp`) are *used* within each level of the categorical fixed effect (`group`). Apparently the model `response ~ comp1 + comp2 + group + (1|sp)` is perfectly valid.